Passing a module object as an input variable to another module
I am thinking of creating a module that sets the top level context (a bunch of shared constants) for a all the modules invoked subsequently. To spare each module from having to create a module object of the context module, I want the entry level module to create that object and pass it to all other modules as an input variable.
I have this code and it works:
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── mod1
│   │   └── mod1.tf
│   ├── mod2
│   │   └── mod2.tf

main.tf:
module mod1 {
    source = "./modules/mod1"
    var1 = "hello"
    var2 = "world"
}

module mod2 {
    source = "./modules/mod2"
    var1 = module.mod1
}

output "mod1" {
    value = module.mod1
}

output "mod2" {
    value = module.mod2
}

modules/mod1/mod1.tf:
variable "var1" {
    type = string
}

variable "var2" {
    type = string
}

output "out1" {
    value = "In module1; got var1 = ${var.var1}"
}

output "out2" {
    value = "In module1; got var2 = ${var.var2}"
}

modules/mod2/mod2.tf:
variable "var1" {
    type = any
}

output "out1" {
    value = "var1 is ${var.var1.out1}, var2 is ${var.var1.out2}"
}

Upon running
$ terraform init && terraform plan

I get
Changes to Outputs:
  + mod1 = {
      + out1 = "In module1; got var1 = hello"
      + out2 = "In module1; got var2 = world"
    }
  + mod2 = {
      + out1 = "var1 is In module1; got var1 = hello, var2 is In module1; got var2 = world"
    }

Is this done usually? If not, are there any risks to this approach, such as Terraform not supporting the feature in a future release?

Related

Can a resource be passed as a variable into a module?
Share common variables among modules
Can I automatically see all child module's output variables without re-defining them in the main root module's output.tf variables?


"I want the entry level module to create that object and pass it to all other modules as an input variable" why not use a .tfvar file?

Your Terraform code is not valid. value = module.<MODULE NAME> is not valid in an output variable.
In the root module, outputs of child modules are available in expressions as module.<MODULE NAME>.<OUTPUT NAME>. For example, if a child module named web_server declared an output named instance_ip_addr, you could access that value as module.web_server.instance_ip_addr.

@RuiJarimba see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64855410/6862601 - that's from where I got the idea of shortcut access to module.<module_name>.

We have multiple "top level" TF modules, each of which control different aspects of our infrastructure and have their own state, and hence can't use the .tfvar route. Specifically, I don't want to symlink a bunch of .tfvar files across my top level modules.

My apologies, I had never seen a module being used like that before.

Why is this question downvoted?

Referring to the object representing a module call is valid Terraform syntax, and you can use that result in any location that expects an object of the appropriate type. This is one of the techniques often used in Module Composition.
However, you've used type = any in your example, which claims that this module could accept a value of any type. A more robust way to write this, which would therefore produce a better error message if the first module ever changes in a way that breaks your assumptions, would be to declare the actual object type you're expecting:
variable "var1" {
  type = object({
    out1 = string
    out2 = string
  })
}

output "out1" {
  value = "var1 is ${var.var1.out1}, var2 is ${var.var1.out2}"
}

The expression in your output "out1" refer directly to the out1 and out2 attributes, so it's inaccurate to write that your variable can accept a value of any type: this module would fail if either of those attributes were omitted.
The special any type constraint is intended only for situations where your module could accept literally any type, such as if you were passing the variable value to a function like jsonencode or yamlencode where any type is allowed.
